# Google Analytics, Custom Segment(s) Based on Custom Dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I've created two custom dimensions in my GA properties: one called employees (internal traffic) and another call non-employees (external traffic).

In my Angular code base, I have an if check flag that puts a user in either category based on their email in my Auth service.

```
   if(res.loginName.match(/@someemail.com/g)) {
      //send user UID to google analytics
      (<any>window).ga('set', 'employees', 1, res.id);
      (<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
    else {
      (<any>window).ga('set', 'non-employees', 2, res.id);
      (<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
```

I'd like to create a custom segment/report based on these dimensions. How do I set up my segment? Employees below is the custom dimension...

[image]

edit: does the below segment seem correct? I am pulling information which is accurate, just like to make sure that my custom dimension and segment are set up properly. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup a segment based on a custom dimension looks like you are in the right place and know how to do that part.

But I think there is something you should change about your custom dimensions.

You should have **ONE** user scope custom dimension(CD) called "Employee Type" or "User Type".

Under this CD, you would send or set the value to "employees" or "non-employees".

Also, the code you use to set should be:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'employee');
```

or
    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'non-employee');

replace "dimension1" with "dimensionXX" where XX represents the index number of the CD, it is NOT the displayed name of your CD.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I believe that did the trick. Are you able to confirm with the recent edit/picture i posted that my custom segment is correct?

Comment: You should rename "employees" CD to "user type", in this CD, you will have values "employees" and "non-employees". Other than that, the segment is correct.

Comment: perfect, made the change, waiting for the reports to re-populate so I can test. Thanks again.